# Import something by its name

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I need to do something like that:

```py
a = input('Import the package: ')
import a
```

Problem: `a` is a string. I do not know how to do it. The best idea I have is to do:

```py
a = input('Import the package: ')
if a == 'numpy':
    import numpy
```

But if I need to `import` many packages, this code can be difficult to read. `a = 'numpy'` is an example. I need this because I am writing a program that needs to import different scripts in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `importlib.import_module()` function. ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module))

```
import importlib

your_string = 'numpy'

i = importlib.import_module(your_string)
```